# Magento2 Custom EAV attribute text in layered navigation

Tags: magento2, eav

Im having multiple custom EAV Attributes which only contain numbers and I want them to be used for filtering in the layered navigation.
I got an extra plugin for the layered navigation but I have to enable "Use in layered navigation" for my attribute which is not possible because it is of type "text".

But my attribute only contains numbers and I want to filter for it to. So is there any option to add it to layered navigation like the internal "price" attribute?

Comment: I'm in your situation, did you find any solution yet?